# message: "Class \"App\\Content\\Definitions\\NovaDependencyContainer\" not found

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to use this package "https://github.com/epartment/nova-dependency-container". I ran the command "`composer require epartment/nova-dependency-container`" and in the file where I want to use it I added at the top:

```
use Epartment\NovaDependencyContainer\HasDependencies;
use Epartment\NovaDependencyContainer\NovaDependencyContainer;
use Epartment\NovaDependencyContainer\ActionHasDependencies;
```

Then to use it:

```
return [
            
            Select::make('Name format', 'name_format')->options([
                0 => 'First Name',
                1 => 'First Name / Last Name',
                2 => 'Full Name'
            ])->displayUsingLabels(),

            NovaDependencyContainer::make([
                Text::make('First Name', 'first_name')
            ])->dependsOn('name_format', 0),

        ];
```

On the line "`NovaDependencyContainer::make([`" it shows an error:

```
Undefined type 'Epartment\NovaDependencyContainer\NovaDependencyContainer'.intelephense(1009)
```

It seems that the package is not being recognized.

Do you know what can be the issue?

I'm using Nova in a slight different way in this case. For example Im not working on the resource file and don't have a fields method, I have like this:

```
public function definition(): array 
{
return 
    [ Select::make('Name format', 'name_format')->options([ 0 => 'First Name', 1 => 'First Name / Last Name', 2 => 'Full Name' ])->displayUsingLabels(),
    NovaDependencyContainer::make([ Text::make('First Name', 'first_name') ])->dependsOn('name_format', 0),         ]; 
}
```

However it works fine without trying to use the package, for example to create a text field it works like this:

```
public function definition(): array { 
    return [ Text::make('First Name') ]; 
}
```

With the     `use HasDependencies;` it shows this error:

```
 "message: "Trait "Epartment\NovaDependencyContainer\HasDependencies" not found" ".
```

Answer (score 0):

1- Add the Epartment\NovaDependencyContainer\HasDependencies trait to your Nova Resource.

2-Add the Epartment\NovaDependencyContainer\NovaDependencyContainer to your Nova Resource fields method.

3- Add the Epartment\NovaDependencyContainer\ActionHasDependencies trait to your Nova Actions that you wish to use dependencies on.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm using Nova in a slight different way in this case. For example Im not working on the resource file and dont have a fields method, I have like this:  public function definition(): array
    {return [      
            Select::make('Name format', 'name_format')->options([
                0 => 'First Name',
                1 => 'First Name / Last Name',
                2 => 'Full Name'
            ])->displayUsingLabels(),
            NovaDependencyContainer::make([
                Text::make('First Name', 'first_name')
            ])->dependsOn('name_format', 0),  ];
}.

Comment: If I use like this it works fine it creates a text field:   public function definition(): array
    {

        return [
            
            
                Text::make('First Name')
            

        ];
    }. But using like above dont works because it seems that the package is not recognized.